# Creating a new Pandas DataFrame from existing one

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

so I have this DataFrame where I have stock symbols, whether the stock was bought or sold and the number of stocks.[Dataframe for stock trading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbGct.png)

Código Negociação is the symbol,
Quantidade is the amount,
Compra/Venda is the action of selling or buying (C for buying V for selling).

I want to make a new dataframe where the symbols are columns and their values are the number of stocks for each day.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqTt.png)

any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that data looks like:

```
    date    symbol  count
0   2019-08-29  a   26
1   2019-08-28  b   16
2   2019-08-28  c   3
3   2019-08-28  c   7
```

just use:

```
df1.pivot_table(index='date', values='count', columns='symbol', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

which gives

```
symbol  a   b   c
date            
2019-08-28  0.0 16.0    10.0
2019-08-29  26.0    0.0 0.0
```

Please, remember to add some sample data not as screenshots :)

Comment: Hello, I was trying to use .pivot only and it was raising an error. The way you described works just fine, but just one more question, is there a way to make a cumulative sum?

Comment: Sure it is. But what and how do you want to accumulate? If you just want cumulative sum of every column rising in time, just do `df1.cumsum()`

Comment: Oh yeah, just a simple .cumsum() at the end does the job, thanks a lot. I was trying crazy kinds of stuff when .pivot was raising error haha. Once again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use the `pivot_table` method and specify in `index` on which column to count it. That's supposed to work.

`sorted_df = original_df.pivot_table(index=['Data do negocio'], aggfunc='size')`